# When does Awesomium's LoadingFrameComplete occurs?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, awesomium

From the Awesomium documentation, it says that the [WebView.LoadingFrameComplete](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/E_Awesomium_Core_WebView_LoadingFrameComplete.htm) event

> Occurs when the page finishes loading a frame.

This sounds quite vague to me. Is this event raised at the same time as the JavaScript `load` event of the window? Or is it the `DOMContentLoaded` event, or a `readystatechange` with `complete` state?

<del>I am not quite sure as I've experienced cases of the `LoadingFrameComplete` event being raised before external JavaScripts have finished executing.</del> (nope, that was the server failing to deliver the files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it corresponds to the `load` event of the window (all resources seems to be loaded, including scripts and deferred scripts)